# Are there any type definitions for JSX in astro?

Tags: typescript, eslint, astrojs

`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return` rule doesn't work well with `.astro` files, because the return type of any jsx is `any`, so any `.map` results in `no-unsafe-return` rule error.

```
---
const cards = [
    {
        href:"https://docs.astro.build/",
        title:"Documentation",
        body:"Learn how Astro works and explore the official API docs.",
    },
    {
        href: "https://astro.build/integrations/",
        title: "Integrations",
        body: "Supercharge your project with new frameworks and libraries.",
    },
    {
        href: "https://astro.build/themes/",
        title: "Themes",
        body: "Explore a galaxy of community-built starter themes.",
    }
];
---

<main>
    {cards.map((card) => (
        // next line has following error: Unsafe return of an `any` typed value. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return)
        <div>{card.href}</div>
    ))}
</main>
```

Are there any type definitions for astro jsx? I found some types inside `node_modules/astro/astro-jsx.d.ts`, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Comment: You decide which ESLint errors are important to you and which aren't. You can turn off rules at the project, file, or line level; you can also declare the return type of a call to `map` easily enough with `as` (see Related links).

Comment: Ofcourse I don't want to turn off ESLint rules. Especially for the entire file, because errors can happen at the frontmatter of the file. Yes, as a temporary solution I could use `as`, but what should I cast it to? And why should I even do that? Shouldn't there already be a type for `<div>` element?

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue and don't want to disable any eslint rule. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn’t. I just made an ESLint override for .astro files where I disabled all no-unsafe-* rules ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eslint-plugin-astro, I raised this as an issue after encountering the same problem [Link](https://github.com/ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-astro/issues/168). The suggested solution from plugin author was to create a `.d.ts` file to declare the below namespace. Then reference that file in my `tsconfig.eslint.json`.

`example.d.ts`

```
import 'astro/astro-jsx'

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        type Element = HTMLElement
        // type Element = astroHTML.JSX.Element // We want to use this, but it is defined as any.
        type IntrinsicElements = astroHTML.JSX.IntrinsicElements
    }
}
```

My `tsconfig.eslint.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    //...
    "example.d.ts"
  ]
}
```